# Backwards Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this figure.

[image]

I tried this code and get this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
    \tikzset{main node/.style={circle, draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=01pt}}
    \tikzset{outer node/.style={thin, black, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white,draw,minimum width=2.25cm,minimum height = .75cm}}
    \newcommand{\ff}{2.5cm}
            
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[main node] (1) {Center};
        \foreach \a/\t in {0/Text, 30/Text, 60/Text, 120/Text, 150/Text, 180/Text}
        \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (\a:\ff) node[outer node]{\t} to (1);
                
    \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (270:2cm) node[outer node]{Text} to (1);
                \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (270:3.5cm) node[outer node]{Text} to (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
    \tikzset{main node/.style={circle, draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=01pt}}
    \tikzset{outer node/.style={thin, black, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white,draw,minimum width=2.25cm,minimum height = .75cm}}
    \newcommand{\ff}{2.5cm}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[main node] (1) {Center};
  \foreach \a/\t in {0/Text, 30/Text, 60/Text, 120/Text, 150/Text, 180/Text}
    \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (\a:\ff) node[outer node]{\t} to (1);           
    \node(2)[outer node, below=1.5cm of 1]{Text};
    \node(3)[outer node, below=1cm of 2]{TExt};
    \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (1) -- (2) {} ;
    \draw[-{Triangle[width=9pt,length=8pt]}, line width=4.5pt] (2)--(3) {} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```